# Convert string column to date

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, date

I have a column of type `string` in the following form

```
23/02/2021
```

how can I either

a) convert this column to Date format

b) create a new column where each cell contains the value in valid date format?

QGIS 3.16

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using this expression in field calculator to create a new field, it works :

> to_date( "string" ,'dd/MM/yyyy')

[image]

More info on the date formatting here :

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html#fromString-2